# Julia BoundsError Means

Tags: debugging, julia

```
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access Tuple{Int64} at index [2]
Stacktrace:
 [1] indexed_iterate
   @ .\tuple.jl:89 [inlined]
```

When I run my Julia code, it shows this BoundsError. What does this mean and how can I solve it?
My code is to find the size of a Vector{Float64}.

```
(m,n)=size(c)
```

where c is a Vector{Float64}.

Answer (score 3):

A `Tuple{Int64}` is a tuple containing a single element. So the error message is saying that you tried to access element `2` of a one-element tuple.

In Julia, vectors are truly one-dimensional, so `size` returns only one value (for eg. `size(1:10)` is just `(10,)`). When you try to assign that to `(m, n)`, you're trying to extract two values from it, hence the error.

Since you know it's a `Vector` already, you know that its number of columns is going to be just `1`. So you can instead just do `n = length(c)` to obtain the number of elements `c` contains.

Comment: If I want to make the input ```c``` can be either a vector or matrix. How can I solve this?

Comment: Depends on what you need the size values for, but one of the ways to solve that is `m, n = size(c, 1), size(c, 2)`.